# Approach to unit-testing large batches of dynamically generated strings

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, batch-processing

My web app has a class for analysing and manipulating the data stored in the URL's hash, which look something like

```
http://myapp.com/#!/location/hornsea/season/spring/facilities/+shop+swimming-airport/size/50
```

To be able to unit test the various permutations I'm storing some URL fragments in an object (e.g.

```
var fragments {
    valid: ["/location/hornsea", "/season/winter","/size/50"],
    invalid: ["location/hornsea", "/seasonwinter","/size/fifty"]
}
```

And then before runing my tests I dynamically build all possible valid and invalid urls and then loop through these, adding a test for each url.

This is fine when I'm running a test for validity of the url, as I just check for true or false in my isValid() method, but when testing for getting the parameters from the URL I don't know how to approach the problem - I have to compare the returned value (e.g. {location: "hornsea""}) with the expected value, but as the string to be analysed is dynamically constructed before running the test I don't have the expected value stored anywhere.

Now, I'm not sure if my approach is overkill - should I care about testing all methods on all possible url structures? Could I set up tests that run against all possible urls when it's easy to do so, but run against a more manageable subset when I need to have finer control over the tests, and yet still manage to cover all eventualities. i.e. could I write a test suite where testing

```
http://myapp.com/season/autumn
```

is adequate enough to cover examples such as the following too.

```
http://myapp.com/location/dungeness/season/autumn
http://myapp.com/location/camberwell/seasonautumn
```

And how could I be sure that I haven't left any gaps? Are there any general approaches to this sort of problem, or is it something very specific to the particular application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this with an [inverse function test](http://theyougen.blogspot.com/2010/12/inverse-function-test-pattern-in.html). You have to write a function (encode) that's the inverse function to your URL parser. The encode function constructs the URL from the valid input values. The test has the form:

```
input = {"location" : "hornsea", "season" : "winter", "size" : "50"}
assert input == parse(encode(input))
```

To get a good best coverage you can use one of the Quickcheck implementations to generate the input values. With generated values you can create subsets of the valid input parameter or shuffle parameters.

Comment: This looks promising, although there will still be a lot of work to do to store the value alongside the url string, and to consider cases where teh url structure (not just teh values) is incorrect

Comment: Normally you wouldn't store the value but generate them. An invalid URL is one missing a parameters, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. In fact, normally missing a parameter is OK. An example of an invalid URL might be /location//hornsea, or /blocation/hornsea, or having conflicting (specifying a location as well as a region) or duplicate (specifying two different locations) - all sorts of ways for it to be invalid, which is why there's a need to store examples of valid/invalid url fragments somewhere as any code that calculates them from scratch would be complex and in need of as much testing as the application itself

Comment: Your application is the test for the test. If a test fails either the app is broken or the test. Looking at the invalid examples like /location//hornsea or /blocation/hornsea there are obvious algorithms to describe the construction. When an URL is composed of prefix + pairs of key:value separated by one slash then everything else is invalid.